# va_arg deal with struct for iOS

Tags: ios

I want to get the all types arguments value,how could deal with The Struct Type?

```
for (NSUInteger i = 2; i < methodSignature.numberOfArguments; i++)
{
    const char *argumentType = [methodSignature getArgumentTypeAtIndex:i];
    switch(argumentType[0]) {
        case 'L':
        case 'q':
        case 'l':
        case 's':
        case 'S':
        case 'B':
        case 'b':
        case 'i':
            obj = @(va_arg(args, int));
            break;
        case 'Q':
            obj = @(va_arg(args, unsigned long long));
            break;
        case 'I':
            obj = @(va_arg(args, unsigned int));
            break;
        case 'f':
        case 'd':
            obj = @(va_arg(args, double));
            break;
        case 'C':
            obj = @(va_arg(args, unsigned char));
            break;
        case 'c':
            obj = @(va_arg(args, char));
            break;
        case '{':
        {
            //how could deal with struct object here?
            obj = @"not support";
            break;
        }
            // 其他id类型
        default: {
            obj = va_arg(args, id);
            if (isCoustomObjcBy(obj))
            {
                obj = getPropertiesAndTypesForClassObjc(obj);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A struct is a concept derived from C, and thus has no reflection information and cannot directly be converted to an object. What you could do is create a wrapper object for the struct (an ocj-C class that wraps the struct). You would have to know the struct in compile-time though, and I do not think there is a way around this.